# Android + List = Crash?

Tags: java, android, list

```
private List<MenuButton>menuButtonList=new ArrayList<MenuButton>();
MenuButton m2=new MenuButton(order,b , vertical, p,name);  
menuButtonList.add(m2);
```

These three lines lead into a crash that happens on the 3rd line, when I add the "MenuButton" to the List. I can't get the error because I use bluestacks and I dont know how to debug with it, anyone has any idea why it happens?

edit:
whole code:

```
public class CreatorView extends View
{

Context c;

boolean quickfix=false;
boolean bin_isEmpty=true;
boolean iftrue=false;
boolean stopnow=false;
String arrowcheck="";
int screenw;
int screenh;
int pixelx;
int pixely;
int smallpixelx;
int smallpixely;
Point arrowsp;

Bitmap grass;
Bitmap dirt;
Bitmap dirt2;
Bitmap dirt3;
Bitmap cloud;
Bitmap bin_Empty;
Bitmap bin_Full;
Bitmap arrowno;
Bitmap arrown;
Bitmap arrowl;
Bitmap arrowr;
Bitmap arrowu;
Bitmap arrowd;
Bitmap arrowul;
Bitmap arrowur;
Bitmap arrowdl;
Bitmap arrowdr;
Bitmap grassSide;
Bitmap grassTop;
Bitmap orange;
Bitmap smallpixel;
Bitmap PixelDetect;


Map.Entry<Bitmap,Point>currentBlock;
Map.Entry<Bitmap,Point>lastBlock;
Map<Bitmap, Point> grassblock = new HashMap<Bitmap, Point>();
Map<Bitmap, Point> dirtblock = new HashMap<Bitmap, Point>();
Map<Bitmap, Point> grassSideBlock = new HashMap<Bitmap, Point>();
Map<Bitmap, Point> grassTopBlock = new HashMap<Bitmap, Point>();
Map<Bitmap, Point> orangeBlock = new HashMap<Bitmap, Point>();
Map<Bitmap, Point> levelMap = new HashMap<Bitmap, Point>();

List<MenuButton>menuButtonList=new ArrayList<MenuButton>(); 

public CreatorView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    this.c=c;


    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    this.screenw= display.getWidth();
    this.screenh=display.getHeight();

    this.PixelDetect   = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(   getResources(),   R.drawable.custom_pixel);
    this.smallpixel   = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(PixelDetect, 3, 3, false);

    this.grass=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.block_grass);
    this.grassSide=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.block_grassside);
    this.grassTop=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.block_grasstop);
    this.orange=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.block_cube1);
    this.dirt=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.block_dirt);
    this.dirt2=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.block_dirt2);
    this.dirt3=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.block_dirt3);
    this.arrowno=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_noclick);
    this.arrown=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_normal);
    this.arrowl=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_left);
    this.arrowr=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_right);
    this.arrowu=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_up);
    this.arrowd=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_down);
    this.arrowul=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_upperleft);
    this.arrowur=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_upperright);
    this.arrowdl=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_downleft);
    this.arrowdr=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_downright);
    this.arrowno=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arrowno, arrowno.getWidth()*3, arrowno.getHeight()*3, false);
    this.bin_Empty=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bin_empty);
    this.bin_Full=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bin_full);
    this.bin_Empty=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bin_Empty, bin_Empty.getWidth()*3, bin_Empty.getHeight()*3, false);
    this.bin_Full=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bin_Full, bin_Full.getWidth()*3, bin_Full.getHeight()*3, false);
    this.arrown=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arrown, arrown.getWidth()*3, arrown.getHeight()*3, false);
    this.arrowl=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arrowl, arrowl.getWidth()*3, arrowl.getHeight()*3, false);
    this.arrowr=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arrowr, arrowr.getWidth()*3, arrowr.getHeight()*3, false);
    this.arrowu=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arrowu, arrowu.getWidth()*3, arrowu.getHeight()*3, false);
    this.arrowd=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arrowd, arrowd.getWidth()*3, arrowd.getHeight()*3, false);
    this.arrowul=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arrowul, arrowul.getWidth()*3, arrowul.getHeight()*3, false);
    this.arrowur=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arrowur, arrowur.getWidth()*3, arrowur.getHeight()*3, false);
    this.arrowdl=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arrowdl, arrowdl.getWidth()*3, arrowdl.getHeight()*3, false);
    this.arrowdr=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arrowdr, arrowdr.getWidth()*3, arrowdr.getHeight()*3, false);

    Menu_Add(arrowno,0,true,"arrows");
    Menu_Add(bin_Empty,1,false,"bin");
    Menu_Add(grassTop,1,true,"grasstop");
    Menu_Add(grassSide,2,true,"grassside");
    Menu_Add(grass,3,true,"grass");
    Menu_Add(dirt,4,true,"dirt");
    Menu_Add(orange,5,true,"orange");

    arrowsp=new Point();
    arrowsp.x=0;
    arrowsp.y=0;
}
private void Menu_Add(Bitmap b,int order,boolean vertical,String name)
{
    Point p=new Point();
    p.x=0;
    p.y=0;
    if(order==0){
        p.x=0;
        p.y=0;
        MenuButton m=new MenuButton(order,b , vertical, p,name);
        menuButtonList.add(m);
    }
    else{
        for (MenuButton m : menuButtonList) {
            if((m.isVertical()==vertical||order==1)&&m.getOrder()+1==order ){
                if(vertical){
                    p.x=0;
                    p.y=m.getP().y+m.getBit().getHeight()+2;
                }
                else{
                    p.x=m.getP().x+m.getBit().getWidth()+2;
                    p.y=0;
                }
                MenuButton m2=new MenuButton(order,b , vertical, p,name);
                menuButtonList.add(m2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

edit 2:

I tried using try and catch to catch the error and display it with toast, but it crashes without displaying.

```
try {
menuButtonList.add(m2);
} 
catch (Exception  e){
Toast.makeText(c, ""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

edit 3:
I ran on the list and it showed it had the first thing I added to it (arrows) as can be seen on the code:

```
if(order==0){
        p.x=0;
        p.y=0;
        MenuButton m=new MenuButton(order,b , vertical, p,name);
        menuButtonList.add(m);
    }
```

, so that means that I can add things to it, because on if(order==0) it adds it just fine, but why after it, it crashes?

Comment: Explain "crash". Please post exception stack.

Comment: I suspect you're not showing us everything. If there is a `private` modifier on a variable, then it can't be in a method and the next 2 lines of code would need to be executed within a method (or a static block).

Comment: I don't know how to get it with bluestacks, it just crashes without an error..

Comment: I added the rest of the code that crashes

Comment: Add the actual error.

Comment: You compile your program with bluestacks? If not, then use your compiling program to also debug it.

Comment: as I said many times, I don't know how. Errors doesn't show up on bluestacks (the emulator im using), and I can't debug with it. ADT doesn't seem to work on my computer, so I can't really tell what is the problem..

Comment: @tom I compile by clicking on the created apk file and loading it on bluestacks.

Comment: If you can't get error or debug, how do you know this is the place it crashes?

Comment: try adding some logs, if you can't debug print out the siwe of the menuButtonList and the content of what you are adding m2 before you make the call, if there is something wrong you will see it. The exception might be not thrown, doesn't mean there is no error.

Comment: @weston because it always worked, and when I remove the line the app works just fine..  and No Anonym ill do that

Comment: @NoaNoNym I did that, I ran on the list and it showed it had the first thing I added to it (arrows) as can be seen on the code, so that means that I can add things to it, because on    if(order==0) it adds it just fine, but why after it, it crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by a few folks in the comments, if there is no stack trace, then there doesn't seem to be any reason to believe that the exception is caused by the code on the third line you showed us. It looks to me as though you're probably causing a `ConcurrentModificationException` here:

```
for (MenuButton m : menuButtonList) {
    if((m.isVertical()==vertical||order==1)&&m.getOrder()+1==order ){
        // ...
        MenuButton m2=new MenuButton(order,b , vertical, p,name);
        menuButtonList.add(m2);
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is caused by you trying to add items to a list while you are iterating over it. Instead, you might be better creating a separate list and then copying its contents into the `menuButtonList` after you have finished your iterating.

```
List<MenuButton> newButtons = new ArrayList<MenuButton>();
for (MenuButton m : menuButtonList) {
    // ...
    MenuButton m2=new MenuButton(order,b , vertical, p,name);
    newButtons.add(m2);
    // ...
}
for (MenuButton newButton : newButtons) {
    menuButtonList.add(newButton);
}
```

Note that adding `menuButtonList.add(m2)` inside that loop **would** trigger the stack trace to report an error on that particular line, but in the absence of the rest of your code, was completely valid.

Comment: I see now, you were correct! Just Instead of copying the contents, I just called return; right after adding. Thanks & thanks everyone for helping, the community here is amazing!